# Is RapidXml thread safe?

Tags: c++, rapidxml

The documentation for [RapidXml](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/) says

> Pool maintains
>   RAPIDXML_STATIC_POOL_SIZE bytes of
>   statically allocated memory. Until
>   static memory is exhausted, no dynamic
>   memory allocations are done. When
>   static memory is exhausted, pool
>   allocates additional blocks of memory
>   of size RAPIDXML_DYNAMIC_POOL_SIZE
>   each, by using global new[] and
>   delete[] operators

I interpret this as: RapidXML uses a global memory pool. Are operations on the global memory pool thread safe? I.e. can I use several instances of RapidXML parser throughout my program without having to consider threading issues?

Answer (score 5):

My interpretation was wrong. The "static memory pool" is an array that is placed on the stack. It is therefore not static as in C++ static array, but rather static as in "not dynamically allocated".

The conclusion: RapidXML does not share the memory pool between instances. The question is therefore invalid.

Comment: Thanks for posting the clarification/new NFO rather than just deleting. :)